# Is it possible to install VS Code extensions in Visual Studio or vice versa?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have Visual Studio installed, but not Visual Studio Code.

There are extensions available in the [Visual Studio Code Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode), but not available in the [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vs), that I would nonetheless love to use in Visual Studio.

Is this possible? Or are the two offerings just fundamentally different? Hacky solutions welcome.

Example: I want [Rainbow-CSV](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mechatroner.rainbow-csv). Double-clicking the VSIX just tells me to try it in VS Code:

[image: Failed installation dialog box]

Do people often run VS and VS Code side by side? There are far more open source offerings for VS Code versus VS.

Comment: Visual Studio uses Visual Studio extensions. VSCode uses VSCode extensions. Do people use them side by side? Who knows. I use them both. Not very often side by side though.

Comment: VSC use JavaScript for extensions, VS uses C++

Comment: @rioV8: VS extensions are written not only in C++, but mostly in C# and sometimes in VB .NET.

Comment: VS Code is an (text) editor based on Electron and Monaco where everything is essentially JavaScript. Visual Studio is a complete IDE and is a purpose built development environment. Despite the similarities in the names, they are fundamentally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think no. VS Code and Visual Studio are not the same, and that includes the ways their extensions work not being the same-

- the way they are run: (VS Code uses JavaScript (interpreted language), and I think Visual Studio uses C++/C#(?) (C# has a intermediate language compiler and a JIT compiler- I'm not sure which is used for Visual Studio extensions. C++ is a compiled language))
- the extension and editor system they are hooking into: compare [Visual Studio's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility) with [VS Code's](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api) (they are vastly different).

Comment: VS extensions are written mostly in C#. It's possible to use any .NET language, i.e., also VB .NET. You can write them in C++ too, but from what I've seen on GitHub, the vast majority is in C#.

Comment: I just want to confirm the answer. The VS and VS Code are totally different programs, and their extensions are absolutely incompatible. I've been developing the extensions for both.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was (naively) hoping that Visual Studio's embedded editor was actually Visual Studio Code, but alas.

Comment: @todb Visual Studio's editor component is written in C++ I think. VS Code's underlying editor is [monaco](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor)